# How can I email myself a file inside a server?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I have a file `access.2022-11-10.txt`

How can I send this file to my email ?

I've tried :

`cat access.2022-11-10.txt | mail -s "TEST"  john@gmail.com`

I see nothing arrive

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say it's blocked due to issues with the `from` address. The default would consist of the system hostname, rather than the correct domain name which may not exist, or consist of `local.localdomain`... Check the man page on how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

If the command didn't produce any errors it suggests that mail is installed on your system. As to what went wrong.....there is a myriad of possibilities. The first place you should be looking is in the mail log file (normally /var/log/mail.log).

Is the host able to connect to the internet to the internet? Resolve DNS names? Did you check your junk mail folder?

BTW most times you want to send a file you likely want to send it as an attachment, not the the body of the email. Check the man page page on your host - the version you have may support attachments. If not, try installing mailx or mutt.